# creating a map of custom object, do I have access to the object methods? (typescript)

Tags: typescript

I'm a beginner at typescript, I need help please :) , I'm trying to do the following: 
I created the first class:

```
class Product{
    public name:string;
    public price: number;

    constructor(name:string,price:number){
        this.name=name;
        this.price=price;
    }

    doublePrice(){
        return this.price*2;
    }
}
```

and the next class is the one that I will be using the most:

```
class MapProduct{
    public date:Date;
    public map: Map<string,Product>;

    constructor(date:string,map:Map<string,Product>){
      this.date=date;
      this.map=map;
    }
}
```

the problem I'm facing is in this current implementation I don't have access to the "doublePrice()" method inside the Map of the MapProduct class for the indivadual Product. Is there a way to have access to this method? I realy don't want to do the following:

```
class MapProduct{
    public date:Date;
    public map: Map<string,Product>;

    constructor(date:string,map:Map<string,Product>){
      this.date=date;
      this.map=map;
    }

doublePrice(key: string){
    let product=this.map.get(key);
    return product.price*2;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you do `let product = this.map.get(key); return product.doublePrice();`? It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: It's still not clear what the issue is. What do you mean by " each class is map of the previous one". Maybe you need to reconsider how you have things structured.

Comment: The problem is that in my case I don't have acces to this method, I got an error: BsNavbarComponent.html:13 ERROR TypeError: this.product.doublePrice is not a function.

Comment: That likely means the key that you're giving it isn't in the map. `get` returns `undefined` on a bad lookup.

Comment: Ok I will try to add some if statement and try again, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please consider editing the code here into a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); you will have a better chance of receiving a meaningful answer.

Comment: @jcalz Just a heads up, you can generate that "ask" link using `[ask]`: [ask].

Comment: @jcalz, Carcigenicate thanks guys, it's just after looking to my code again and again,it turns out that my issue is not with type script, it actually with using maps while targeting es5, (I m working on an angular project).